# Add values to dataframe based on values in other column

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to add values to a column based on non-unique values in another column. For example, say I have a dataframe with a currently empty column that looks like this:

| Site | Species Richness |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0 |
| A | 0 |
| A | 0 |
| B | 0 |
| B | 0 |

I want to assign known species richness values for each site. Let's say site A has species richness 3, and site B has species richness 5. I would like the output to be:

| Site | Species Richness |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 5 |
| B | 5 |

How do I input species richness values for specific sites?

I've tried this:

```
rows_update(df, tibble(Site = A, richness = 3))
rows_update(df, tibble(Site = B, richness = 5))
```

But I get an error message saying "'x' key values are not unique"

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need quotes on `A` i.e. `Site = "A"`

Comment: According to `?rows_update` `The key values must uniquely identify each row (i.e. each combination of key values occurs at most once), and the key columns must exist in both x and y.`. Here, it is not uniquely identifying

Answer (score 0):

Here, we could make use of join `on` from `data.table` and assign `:=` the corresponding column of 'SpeciesRichness'.  It would be more efficient

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[data.table(Site = c('A','B'), SpeciesRichness = c(3, 5)), 
       SpeciesRichness := i.SpeciesRichness, on = .(Site)]
```

---

The issue with `?rows_update` is that the `by` column should be uniquely identifying in both data.

> The two tables are matched by a set of key variables whose values must uniquely identify each row.

With 'df', the values are replicated 3 times for 'A' and 2 for 'B'.  Using `dplyr`, we can do a `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   left_join(tibble(Site = c('A', "B"), new = c(3, 5))) %>% 
    transmute(Site, SpeciesRichness = new)
```

-output

```
#   Site SpeciesRichness
#1    A               3
#2    A               3
#3    A               3
#4    B               5
#5    B               5
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Site = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), 
SpeciesRichness = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dataframe with `Site` and `Richness` value and join them together.

In base R :

```
df1 <- data.frame(Site = rep(c('A', 'B'), c(3, 2)))
df2 <- data.frame(Site = c('A', 'B'), richness = c(3, 5))

df1 <- merge(df1, df2)
df1

#  Site richness
#1    A        3
#2    A        3
#3    A        3
#4    B        5
#5    B        5
```

You can also use `match` :

```
df1$richness <- df2$richness[match(df1$Site, df2$Site)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define the values then use `case_when`

```
x <- 3
y <- 5

df %>% 
  mutate(SpeciesRichness= case_when(Site=="A" ~ x, 
                                    Site=="B" ~ y))
```

Output:

```
  Site SpeciesRichness
1    A               3
2    A               3
3    A               3
4    B               5
5    B               5
```